# How does twitter bootstrap's dropdown bind to MVC model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How does MVC model binding will work with twitter's drop down list?

so if I have twitters drop down list as

```
<form id="profileform" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-antiforgery="true" asp-controller="profile" asp-action="save" class="form-horizontal">    
   <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Select
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Client A</a>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Client B</a>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Client C</a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <button id="btnSave" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm">Save</button>
</form>
```

and then i have model

```
public class ProfileModel
{
    public int ClientID {get;set;}
}
```

and controller

```
   public class ProfileController:
   {
      public IActionResult Save(ProfileModel model)
      {
          // do something here
      }
   }
```

How does a selected item's value will get bind to a model property?

Comment: You have to set `name="ClientID"` for your dropdown.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai but how does clientid get set? there is no `value` attribute in `<a>` ?If i use html `select` element the each `option` element has `value` attribute, but this is not the case with bootstrap since it uses `ul` and `li` element to construct the dropdown list

Comment: What library for select do you use ?

Comment: You need a form control to bind to your model - your just creating `<div>` and `<a>` elements to generate a menu, not a `<select>` (dropdownlist)

Comment: there is form element in above snippet